# How to change button text in bootstrap 4 collapse buttons

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the text of the button when the unordered list is expanded to "Close" and when is collapsed to "More". The problem is, when I click the button the string "More" remains while the list is expanded and then starts to work as intended but in reverse. I know I am missing something. Any help would be much appreciated

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<ul class="category-menu" id="category1">
    <li>First Ul li1 </li>
    <li>First Ul li2 </li>
    <li>First Ul li3 </li>
    <li>First Ul li4</li>

  </ul>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-block btn-filter-expand " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="category1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="category1">More
</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
```

```
$('button.btn-filter-expand').click(function () {
   $(this).text(function (i, old) {
      return old == 'More' ? 'Close' : 'More';
   });
 });
```

I have also tried the script below

```
    $('button.btn-filter-expand').html('More');

    $('button.btn-filter-expand').on('click',function () {
        $(this).html('');
        

        if ($(this).prev('.category-menu').hasClass('show')) {
            $(this).html('Close');
        } else {
            $(this).html('More');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the JQuery code, try below code

```
    $('button.btn-filter-expand').html('More');
    $('button.btn-filter-expand').click(function () {
         if($(this).html() == "More") {
                $(this).html('Close');
         } else {
            $(this).html('More');
         }
     });
```